# Understanding the basics of AC coupling

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, detector

The real case I am working on: I need to connect a CZT (Cadmium-Zinc-Tellurium) detector to a custom ASIC input (a Charge Sensitive Amplifier of which I do not know the input impedance, if that matters). The recommended way of doing this is through the use of an AC-coupling circuit. I need to dimension the circuit.

The theory: the most simple and straightforward way of connecting the detector to the ASIC would be a capacitor C. In the image below, the current source represents the detector, C is the decoupling capacitor and the OpAmp represents the ASIC (values of I and C are meaningless)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3vxZP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a good understanding of why we need it and why it is done like that (or at least, I think I do). My doubts come from an implementation I have from another project.

In a different project, using the exact same detector and ASIC, the people responsible for the project adopted the following solution:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmzYqx.png)</sup>

The values are the real values used in their schematic.

Questions:

1) why do they use a resistor?

2) why is the resistor placed before the C and not after? If the AC-coupling is basically an high-pass filter, shouldn't it be placed after?

3) what would be the procedure to calculate those values, in any case? My confusion here is deriving from the fact that the input signal is an "unknown" by itself (it can be approximated by a "spike", if you want).

Thanks!

Comment: The resistor will (slowly) remove any charge buildup. Thus moving cables, or moving objects around the sensor, may induce charges, and that resistor lets the charge "bleed" off.

Comment: adding to the comment by analogsystemsrf, the detector itself can be thought of as a small capacitor.  A gamma ray puts some charge on this capacitor.  The resistor has little effect on the fast voltage pulse that is caused by this quick change in the charge, but provides a known resistance to bleed off the accumulated charges after a period of time.  Without the resistor, the charge would eventually bleed off through (unknown) surface leakage in the detector and leakage on the circuit board, the input capacitor, and so on.  The resistor just keeps things more controlled and known.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, now the purpose of that resistor is more clear. Which means I can probably consider the value of the capacitance only when plugging in the numbers for the AC-coupling formulas, disregarding the resistor. Will investigate the resistor value :)